# Sort by filename with du command

Tags: linux, disk-usage, sort

I'd like to be able to sort the output of "du -ah /" --exclude=/tmp >> files.txt" by filename, not by size.  How can this be done on Linux?  I'm comparing files on two different servers and then using a diff program to see the differences.

Note:

This will get a list of all files recursively, and output them to a file named "files.txt".  The goal is to sort the files by filename for two systems and then compare every file using a diff tool (ie: TortoiseSVN Diff).  Without sorting the list, it will be more difficult to see what files are different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try issuing `du -ah / --exclude=/tmp | sort -k 2 >> files.txt`