# Where is the KEYDEF in sort command?

Tags: sort, size

I need to sort the results of 'du' command by file or folder name, file size, or last modified time in various situations, and appending ' | sort -k 2' command after 'du' command sorts the results by folder names, which I learned from this question.
[Sort by filename with du command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/365662/sort-by-filename-with-du-command)

In the sort command manual (RHEL 7.6), it reads
-k, --key=KEYDEF          sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type
KEYDEF is F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]] for start and stop position, where F is a
field number and C a character position in the field;

but still don't understand what it means.

Does F=2 means file name?
Then what is the F for the file size or last modified time?
Then where can I find the 'KEYDEF'?

I carefully read this document:
https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html
but still can't find the information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F is the field number, and by default, the `sort` command defines a field as text surrounded by white space. The -b and -t options can change the default; the document you reference contains a lengthy headache-inducing discussion about the details of specifying field separators depending on locale and such.

You ask "what is the F for the file size or last modified time?". `sort` doesn't have the notion of file size or modified time. Since your goal is to filter the output of `du`, run your `du` command and count the fields.

For example, when I run `du` without option, I get two fields per line, the size and the file/directory name:

```
$ du . 
8       ./ruby
4       ./nextcloud/data/nextcloud
12      ./nextcloud/data/database/nextcloud
4       ./nextcloud/data/database/performance_schema
4       ./nextcloud/data/database/mysql
... etc ...
```

In case you need to sort files and directories under the current directory, `du . | sort -n` does the trick, because `sort` sorts on the first field by default. The -n option is required to sort numerically rather than alphanumerically:

```
$ du . | sort -n 
4       ./bitwarden/data/icon_cache
4       ./.cache/obexd
4       ./.cache/pip/wheels/2c/4a/61/5599631c1554768c6290b08c02c72d7317910374ca602ff1e5
4       ./.cache/pip/wheels/33/56/20/ebe49a5c612fffe1c5a632146b16596f9e64676768661e4e46
4       ./.cache/pip/wheels/88/a7/30/e39a54a87bcbe25308fa3ca64e8ddc75d9b3e5afa21ee32d57
4       ./.cache/pip/wheels/fc/a8/66/24d655233c757e178d45dea2de22a04c6d92766abfb741129a
... etc ...
```

You can add -r to display big files first.

To sort by pathname:

```
du . | sort -k 2
```

I don't have a quick solution for sorting by filename, i.e. by the last component of the pathname. I think `sort` alone can't to that, because you would need to figure out which subfield is the filename, and the subfield number varies. Here is a partial solution (it only works for pathnames that contain a slash):

```
$ du . | sed 's|\(.*\)/\(.*\)|\1/\2 \2|' | sort -k3
5639116 .
12      ./.cache/pip/http/9/8/7/0 0
12      ./.cache/pip/http/9/c/b/c/0 0
12      ./.cache/pip/http/c/0/4/0/0 0
12      ./.cache/pip/http/f/0/3/0 0
12      ./.cache/pip/http/f/e/d/0 0
136     ./.cache/pip/http/4/8/d/7/0 0
164     ./.cache/pip/http/a/0 0
16      ./.cache/pip/http/0/0/9/7/0 0
16      ./.cache/pip/http/2/8/0 0
... etc ...
```

I don't know if there is any combinations of options that makes the `du` command print the modified time. If there is one, let me know, and I will point out which field it is.